# Add directory to the jar which will be for insert external jars or classes

Tags: java, jar, gradle, directory, external

I have a jar file which is my application (which is builded by gradle) and I want to add directory which is "ext" folder for extensible files (jars or classes). How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this into your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'ext', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

and synchronize the project files.

Comment: what does it mean "and synchronize the project files"?

Comment: For Android Studio (IntellijIDEA based IDE), it means that -> http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-android/cbl-android-1.0b2/images/sync-gradle.png